# Python for Absolute Beginners: Chapter 2 #Personal_Greeter

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, brackets

A simple question concerning brackets. I'm intrigued to know why brackets sometimes print, and sometimes remain 'invisible'? In this case I can give an example of the code and the answer to show what I mean.

If I put in:

```
 name = "Larry"
 print(name)
 print("Hi", name)
 raw_input("Enter to exit program")
```

Why do I get this answer:

```
 Larry
 ('Hi', 'Larry') 
 Enter to exit program
```

Larry without brackets, nor single quotes. Yet ('Hi', 'Larry') is with brackets and single quotes?

Can someone point out what's happening please?

Comment: The most recent edition of Python for Absolute Beginners is the third edition published in January 2010, which is for Python 3.  You are using Python 2.7.  In Python 2.7 `print` is a statement and needs no parenthesis.  Thus when Python 2.7 sees `print("Hi", name)` it sees `print` and the tuple `("Hi", name)`.  If you were using Python 3 it would interpret the parenthesis as part of a function call with two arguments.  The correct solution to your problem is to use Python 3 as that is what your book is teaching you.

Comment: Btw, In U.S. English `[]` are brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The expression in brackets is interpreted as a special datatype,  a tuple - a thing that collects some values together. Single and double quotes can be used alternatively in Python to denote strings of characters.

In Python 2.7 the brackets are unnecessary when you `print` something and can lead to interpretation problems. Remove them and see what happens.

Compare with this code:

```
a = ('hello', 3) #a tuple
print a
print 'hello', 3
```

On the other hand, in Python 3 the brackets would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent edition of Python for Absolute Beginners is the third edition published in January 2010, which is for Python 3.  You are using Python 2.7.  In Python 2.7 `print` is a statement and needs no parenthesis.  Thus when Python 2.7 sees `print("Hi", name)` it sees `print` and the tuple `("Hi", name)`.  If you were using Python 3 it would interpret the parenthesis as part of a function call with two arguments.  The correct solution to your problem is to use Python 3 as that is what your book is teaching you.

Python 2.7:

```
>>> name = "Larry"
>>> print(name)
Larry
>>> print("Hi", name)
('Hi', 'Larry')
```

Python 3:

```
>>> name = "Larry"
>>> print(name)
Larry
>>> print("Hi", name)
Hi Larry
```

It's possible to make Python 2.7 act like Python 3 by doing `from __future__ import print_function`, but I would recommend against that as you will run into other incompatibilities as you go through your book.

Comment: Great, thanks. Just a supplementary question, can you run Python 2.7 and Python 3 on a computer (separately)? As I mentioned on another post I need 2.7 for a course I'm doing, so rather than updating it would be useful to call 2.7 or 3 as needed.

Comment: @user7409665 Yes, you can have both installed concurrently.